# Add Custom profile name to Package.xml

Tags: ant, custom-profile

I have been searching through a way add custom profile names in to Package.xml file. According to my scenario i shall add custom profiles only instead of all other standard profiles. Sample custom profile names are : '`Sample profile1', 'Sample profile2`' etc... 
However when I add the name in to the package.xml and run the ant script, it returns me an error.

```
 Error: An object 'Sample profile1' of type Profile was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

Is there any proper way to add these names?

Comment: The Error Normally comes when you mention incorrect name on package.xml. When u retrieve Profile, it may not coming in the folder and when u are trying to deploy the same, it is giving you the error as it is not present in profile folder.
Can you check if the profile contains any special character? Share the package.xml format that you're using.

Comment: Do you have the *profiles* folder as *src/profiles* in your zip file? If you mention anything in the package.xml, that needs to be in your src directory as well. The error says that the profile name was mentioned in package.xml but is not available in the zip file.

Comment: Thanks. So what you’re saying is the way I added the profile name is correct?

Comment: yes.. check the profile folder and confirm if profile has been retrieved or not. I am sure it has not retrieved.

Comment: I have added details around your original question, the problem and how to resolve it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As for your question:**

> I have been searching through a way add custom profile names in to Package.xml file.

You can add the names of the custom profiles the way you have mentioned in your post, i.e., let's say if I have a custom profile named *"Read Only - Custom"*, and that I want to retrieve/deploy it using ant, it will look like as below in my package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>Admin</members>
    <members>Read Only - Custom</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

---

**Now for your error:**

The reason why you are getting this error is because you added the profile name but that does not really exist in the package that you are trying to deploy. So let's say if I wish to add a particular source to my org and that I have details as in the image below:
[image]

And if I run a deploy task using this package.xml, I will get exactly the same error that you are receiving.

> All Component Failures:
>
> 1. package.xml (Read Only - Custom) -- Error: An object 'Read Only - Custom' of type Profile was named in package.xml, but was not found in
>      zipped directory

---

**Resolution:**

The resolution for this is to make sure that you have all the components that are referred in your *package.xml* available in the source folder that you are trying to deploy. If you don't have that already, then use the same package.xml to retrieve contents from the source sandbox to be able to deploy it to target sandbox.

Comment: Wildcard * doesn't work?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes it does. This was more to explain if you have something in your package.xml and not in source folder to be deployed. And at times you may not want to retrieve/deploy all profiles if they are not relevant to the application.